# How to get an indicator for xpad in the taskbar

Tags: 20.04, notes

I was looking for a simple sticky notes type software and it turns out there's no indicator for xpad in the taskbar but there should be.

Comment: Interestingly enough there is an indicator on my system for xpad, but it is very slow to get there...